# How to focus a specific node when selected tab changes in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I want to set focus to a specific node in the content of a Tab. I added a **ChangeListener** to **selectedItem** property as follows (assume that the class contains a field named **secondNode** of type **Node**):

```
tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observable, Tab oldValue, Tab newValue) {
        if (newValue != null) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    secondNode.requestFocus();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

However, this does not work. I assume the reason is because TabPane performs some additional actions, which affect focus, after the new tab has been selected (but, looking through [TabPane source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/master/rt/file/e71070b0e0c0/javafx-ui-controls/src/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.java), I can't figure out what). If I single-step through this code in a debugger, it works as expected, so it appears to be a race condition. If this is so, how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try replacing the Runnable with a Task:

```
        new Thread( new Task<Void>() 
        {
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception // This is NOT on FX thread 
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void succeeded()  // This is called on FX thread.
            {
                secondNode.requestFocus();
            }

        }).start();
```

Comment: Hmm, this would work, no doubt, but it depends on the time the thread is sleeping. If you put too low a value, you still may have a race condition, and if the value is too high there would be a visible shift of focus. So it's kind of a hackish solution. Still, it is a solution, so I'll accept it.

Comment: Yeh, I agree its hackish but unfortunately I've had to employ this technique several times for other aspects of FX. I'm hoping its better in FX 8.

Comment: As you said, this is wrong and I think this should be reported as a bug to OpenJavaFX.