# JAVA FX ScrollPane Does Not Allow To Request Focus On A Field

Tags: java, javafx, focus, setfocus, focusable

I'm developing a JavaFX client. It is a two-pane software. The left pane is a list that shows several applications (with different layouts) developed for the client (`Application_1`, `Application_2`, etc). The right pane is the place where the `Application_N` is shown.

An application, that is shown in the right pane of the software, has the following java class hierarchy:

`BorderPane -> Application` (application class developed by me).

The `Application` class has a `Node` attribute (`Node` body;) which contains a form, and this form contains a `Field`.

When the application is being displayed in the mentioned right pane It calls the method `requestFocus()`, and this method (that is overwritten from the JavaFX `Node` class) has the duty to request focus (using this time the original `requestFocus()` method from the JavaFX `Node` class) for the mentioned field.

This procedure works good. However, the problem is when I want to add a `ScrollPane` that will contain the `Node` body. It seems to be that the `ScrollPane` is disallowing the request focus method to the field in the body.

The code written below is from **Application.java**

```
  Node body;

  body = getBody(); // getBody() builds the UI of this application

  scrollPanel = new ScrollPane();
  scrollPanel.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
  scrollPanel.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
  scrollPanel.setFitToWidth(true);
  scrollPanel.setFitToHeight(true);
  scrollPanel.getStyleClass().add("application");
  scrollPanel.setContent(body);

  this.setCenter(scrollPanel);

  ...
```

And now, when the application is going to be displayed it executes the code below:

```
   public void create(){
       requestFocus();  
   }

   @Override
   public void requestFocus(){
    accountField.requestFocus(); //using the method from the JavaFX node class
}
```

I repeat that the problem is happening **when I put the scroll pane in my hierarchy**. I would be grateful if someone has a comment or solution to this. Thank you.

Comment: Does it work if you wrap the requestFocus call in [Platform.runLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) or perhaps using this [task hack for delayed focus control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594035/how-to-focus-a-specific-node-when-selected-tab-changes-in-javafx)?

Comment: I have tried with that solution. Wrapping the requestFocus method in Platform.runLater(). Nevertheless, it only works sometimes. I don't know why. It might be something with the Java FX thread, but not sure at all. @jewelsea

Comment: I'm going to try the second option that you gave. Thanks. @jewelsea

Comment: [That task hack using Thread.sleep()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594035/how-to-focus-a-specific-node-when-selected-tab-changes-in-javafx) is not my prefered option due to it isn't completely accurate. You have to play with the time. However, it works and I will take it while I keep researching what is the relationship between the scroll pane (because without it the request focus on my specific child node works) and the Java FX thread. Thanks. @jewelsea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the scrollPane incomplete and bugged.
At this stage, my solution was to copy openjfx ScrollPane[Behavior|Skin] sources and make the nescessary hacks in.

One done, you can alter the focus stealing behavior in ScrollPaneBehavior